# Laravel vuejs SPA on localhost - cors fails

Tags: php, laravel, cors, laravel-sanctum

I use laravel9 and vuejs3 with laravel sanctum SPA authentication on a Fedora 36 os.

I created 2 apache sites on local host with this virtual hosts

00-backend.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.compagnon-backend.fr
    ServerAlias compagnon-backend.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/compagnon-backend/public
        <Directory /var/www/compagnon-backend/public>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and 00-frontend.conf in  /etc/httpd/conf.d

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.compagnon-frontend.fr
    ServerAlias compagnon-frontend.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/compagnon-frontend
        <Directory /var/www/compagnon-frontend>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The relevant content in .env of backend

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL= www.compagnon-backend.fr

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=compagnon-backend.fr
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=*.compagnon-frontend.fr
SPA_URL=https://www.compagnon-frontend.fr
```

config.cors

```
<?php

return [

  
    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'register',
        'user/password',
        'forgot-password',
        'reset-password',
        'user/profile-information',
        'email/verification-notification',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['https://www.compagnon-frontend.fr', 'https://compagnon-frontend.fr'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

config/session.php

```
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    return [
        'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
        'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
        'expire_on_close' => false,
        'encrypt' => false,
        'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
        'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),
        'table' => 'sessions',
        'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),
        'lottery' => [2, 100],
        'cookie' => env(
            'SESSION_COOKIE',
            Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
        ),
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
        'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),
        'http_only' => true,
        'same_site' => 'lax',
    
    ];

config/sanctum.php
<?php
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    'guard' => ['web'],
    'expiration' => null,
    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

With this configuration both sites works but from the frontend trying to login I get this message

> Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Failed)

I could not manage to fix this. I need help. Thank you.

ADDITIONAL EDIT AFTER FIRST COMMENT

In kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
     \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
     \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel through API calls? In that case you should need a CORS middleware. Here you have a package that should solve your issue https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: Thank you for help. Yes I do. I had the laravel-cors package installed but in protected $middleware I had only \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class so I added \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class, but there is no change. I update my post with this.

Comment: Sorry, did you publish config file using `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"`? And after that you have to set `paths` array with routes that you wish to have the CORS service enabled

Comment: I don't understand. I already have the config/cors  as you can see in my original post.

Comment: Sorry I missed your `config/cors.php` file, taking a look on it I saw that you have set allowed path, which is required, so the only point I see is in  `    'allowed_origins' =>` I think it should include the extension `.fr` or at least, a `.*` wilcard.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake copying the original file. In realty the .fr exists in the application. But it doesn't work. I update my original post with this.

Comment: Gasp! I think I'm almost blind. Have you take a look over common problems in package readme? It mentions some suggestion about ordering middleware, clearing config cache, etc.